# How do they hide URL when mouseover?

Tags: javascript, url, hide, status, adsense

Everybody knows that the good old school `windows.status` is not working anymore when `mouseover` a link. However, I found a site which seems to be blanking out the URL link while the link is always below the mouse.

**More details below:**
*Answered*

Comment: Why is the URL shortened? Why do you require the status bar not show the link's location?

Comment: Why would you want to change(ie break) the browser's default functionality?

Comment: In Chrome 8, that site's links that are below that iframe do not work at all (shows why you shouldn't be trying to do funny business like that)

Comment: shorten url not to get indexed.. and don't want the website owner to see we are discussing about his site here..

Comment: i was wondering how they did it since the windows status isnt working anymore and i was looking for alternatives.. for affiliate link purpose..

Comment: Clicking on the link takes me inkpots.info. Looks like SPAM

Comment: yes.. i already said do not click.. but thats not the point.. i want to know how they hide the url from displaying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google AdSense uses an [`onclick`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) JavaScript event handler to redirect the user in this case, not the `href` attribute of a link. Here is the (approximate) source code of the element (several iframes deep) that traps the user's mouse click. According to Firebug, the user's mouse click goes to the outer [`td` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6).

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" onclick="ga(this,event)" onmouseout="cs()" onmouseover="return ss('go to www.Solar-Aid.org','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onfocus="ss('go to www.Solar-Aid.org','aw0')" class="ch" id="taw0">
  <div style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; width: 116px;">
    <font face="impact, poster bodoni, geneva" style="font-size: 20px;">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;" class="textcolor" onmouseout="cs()" onmouseover="return ss('go to www.Solar-Aid.org','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')" onfocus="ss('go to www.Solar-Aid.org','aw0')" href="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/iclk?sa=l&amp;ai=BBuZpfBTrTMqHJ8zLsQfDsviMDfKumAKzyl3SmZ0CABABGAEgACgEOACCAQZjYS1wdWKIAQGQAfDkArIBDXNvbGFyLWFpZC5vcme6AQoxMjB4NjAwX2FzwAEC2gEZaHR0cDovL3d3dy5Tb2xhci1BaWQub3JnL8gDFw&amp;num=1&amp;adurl=http://www.Solar-Aid.org/&amp;client=ca-pub-0563973986972825&amp;nm=34" target="_top" id="aw0">
        Solar Energy Charity
      </a>
    </font>
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- snip -->
  </div>
</td>
```

The actual text links are irrelevant; they are farther down than the height of the spammer's mouse-following iframe (which has a set opacity of 0.1, so it remains nearly invisible to the user). `ga` is just a function that changes the outside window's URL using [`top.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
function ga(o, e) {
  if(document.getElementById) {
    a = o.id.substring(1);
    // snip
    top.location.href = document.getElementById(a).href;
  }
}
```

By the way, there's no need to worry about the spammer making money when you click on that particular ad because it is a [public service ad](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10035) (PSA). Clicks on PSAs do not earn any money for a publisher, and Google can show PSAs for several reasons including that the AdSense account has not been approved.

Comment: Yes, i think you are right. So to sum up everything, we are mouseover the actual td element instead of the text link but on click it would redirect to the link instead. If i want to create my own mouse over area and then onclick go to the javascript feed links(assuming i created my links through a file external.js returning ahref links), can you write a simple code structure to do this? Or even reference would be great. THANKS A MILLION IN ADVANCE.

Comment: @jeremy: I'm not going to write your code for you, especially because it would be very deceptive in nature. If you can't do it yourself, just hire someone to do it, not that I think that it's the right thing to do.

Comment: i understand you. but initially i brought the example up is because i thought it is a new way to replace windows.status. What i intend to use is on a static block of ad in my blog. The javascript is my affiliate link and the product description. So everytime when the visitor visits, it would bring up random product but when mouse over it wont show the affiliate link. and no it will not follow the mouse.. let me know if this will work? i have to thank you either  =) , i guess im not that clever after all.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm unclear on what you're trying to do (since the example link is gone), but does this seem right?

HTML:

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function() {
location.href="www.yahoo.com";
return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, i like it that this is easy to hide the url. but im looking towards dynamic(js rotating link feed) link rather than static. is it possible?

Comment: @jeremy, then the question really isn't about hiding the status text. Jeff gave you the generic method for hiding the status text, and it works for any sort of application, including switching the url. That can easily be achieved with an array of urls and incrementing the index in a setInterval()

Comment: Yes, what box9 said.  I think your original question has been answered.  It should be fairly straightforward in javascript to choose a link from an array of links.  If you have any trouble with the JS, post a new question about it pointing out specifically where you're running into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

class="vmenuballon" onclick="javascript:parent.location.href='home'"   onmouseover="window.tip='back'"alt="back" title="back" >Home