# How does Google's search result links work?

Tags: redirect

Google redirects search result links to http://www.google.com/url?blah but when you hover over the link, the correct destination appears in the bottom of the browser. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

at first the href of the url is actually what shows up in the bottom of the browser. they use the onmousedown event to change it as soon as you click it. its hard to inspect because even right-clicking it rewrites the url. try inspecting the first link in the DOM inspector via right-click, and then scroll through the inspector to the NEXT search result link and you can see the original href. Then right-click it and watch it change. Here is a sample of the javascript extracted.

```
  onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNExXX4MUzCuBu_Pvbj4O6N2xise-g','','0CCUQFjAB',null,event)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question does a good job of explaining how this is achieved:

[How do they hide URL when mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251749/how-do-they-hide-url-when-mouseover)